# Push Notifications Raspberry Pi

Tags: api, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, raspberry-pi

Okay so i'm after a bit of advice more than a definitive answer, not entirely sure this is the correct place to ask but i'll fire away anyway!

I've recently bought the Raspberry Pi 2 and I want to use it for a little project I want to do. My idea is to use the RP2 to send push notifications to my phone based on location, my main use will be to send me the train times and platforms when I'm leaving work/arriving at a 'trigger' location.

Before I start I'm just trying to map in out in my head, the current workflow I'm thinking is as follows.

I'll most likely have to create a native app to allow it to monitor my current location.

- Enter home station into app
- RP2 will watch app for changes in location (location gets sent to RP2)
- If location matches trigger point then make a request to [insert train timetable API here]
- Return the next 5 train times and platforms
- Pass this information to a service such as [Instapush](https://instapush.im/)
- Use this information to send a push notification to phone

I understand this is a very broad and basic outline but I wanted to get some feedback to see if thats the sort of workflow I'll be looking at?

Likewise, if anyone has any good resources they can point to then it'll be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to set up your own "[MQTT Broker](https://github.com/owntracks/owntracks/wiki/MQTTBroker)" then [Owntracks](http://owntracks.org/) may be a basis to accomplish what you want.  As far as push services are concerned I prefer Pushover.